# Ayuda con closure y callback

Tags: javascript, angular, callback

podrán ayudarme con este ejemplo que tengo en Angular 9:

Quiero saber qué pasa con mi variable **map**, y como puedo utilizarla dentro del callback.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMap } from '@angular/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ej',
  templateUrl: './ej.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ej.component.css']
})
export class EjComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(GoogleMap, { static: false }) map: GoogleMap; // Esta variable es del tipo **GoogleMap**

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.map; // Esta variable es del tipo **GoogleMap**
  }

  searchLocation(){

    this.map; // Esta variable es del tipo **GoogleMap**

    this.geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
    this.geocoder.geocode(this.geocoderRequest, function(results, status) {

     this.map; // Esta variable es del tipo **ANY**

    })
  }
```

No sé como hacer dentro del callback tener la variable **map**.

Podrán ayudarme?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas una variable dentro de un callback tipo función pierdes las variables del contexto principal, lo que deberías hacer es usar una función flecha.

```
this.geocoder.geocode(this.geocoderRequest, (results, status) => {

     this.map; // Esta variable es del tipo **ANY**

    })
```

Comment: Mil gracias!!! No sabes cuanto me complicó la vida esto, y la solución era una sencilla!!